# Want to send an UDP frame by packing a bytes list

Tags: python, struct, pack

```
data_values=[]

total_packet_size = 64
endianness = '<'

for _ in range(total_packet_size):
    data_values+=[int((args.cmd * 32767) + 32768) >> 10,
    int((args.cmd * 32767) + 32768) >> 2 & 0xFF
    ]
packet_data = struct.pack(f'{endianness}{total_packet_size*2}H', *data_values)
```

Here I want to pack my data_values but when I print it I got this :
b' \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00'

But my data_values is this :
[32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 32, ...]

So normaly I should get this :
b' \x00\x20....... '

I try a lot of tests like change the variable type but nothing work

Comment: What is `args.cmd`? `struct.pack('<H', 8192)`, for example, would give you `b'\x00\x20'`, so something like `packetdata = b''.pack(struct.pack('<H', f(args.cmd)) for _ in range(total_package_size))` for a suitable `f` to turn `args.cmd` into the appropriate 16-bit value.